# Grape: Rescue from invalid JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec, ruby-grape

**First:**

I'm using grape for building my API (Rails 4). When someone is sending an invalid JSON body (e.g. forgot the last `}`), the following error is raised:

```
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (795: unexpected token at '{"foobar": 1234

')
```

I tried it with grapes `rescue_from :all` option, but this doesn't work. Inside the stacktrace, I don't see the grape gem involved. It seems that this error is thrown from actionpack:

```
  .gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:53:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'
  .gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:32:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
  .gems/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:23:in `call'
```

But what would be the best way to catch those errors, return a `400: Bad Request` errors, and include the `unexpected token at '{"foobar": 1234` message inside the json response?

**Second:**

I tried to test this with RSpec, but didn't have any luck on sending a raw request with an invalid JSON. I tried it with

```
post "/my_route", '{some invalid json'
```

but this doesn't throw the error from above. I thought since Rails 4, the second parameter, passed as a string, is treated like the raw body?

Comment: I think you should consider separating this question into two questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately ActionDispatch runs well ahead of it ever getting to a controller so you're not going to be able to do this with Grape (AFAIK).

We ran into this issue too and found a [wonderful article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware) from the Thoughtbot guys on the subject.

Use the Curb gem to make the shotty calls:

```
require 'curb'
it 'sends poorly formatted json' do
  broken_json = %Q|{"notice":{"title":"A sweet title"#{invalid_tokens}}}|
  resp = Curl.post("http://#{host}:#{port}#{path}", broken_json)

  expect(resp.response_code).to eq 500
end
```

Thoughtbot recommends writing a middleware class to capture future JSON parse errors like this:

```
# in app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb
class CatchJsonParseErrors
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      @app.call(env)
    rescue ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError => error
      if env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] =~ /application\/json/
        error_output = "There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: #{error}"
        return [
          400, { "Content-Type" => "application/json" },
          [ { status: 400, error: error_output }.to_json ]
        ]
      else
        raise error
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try! One more question: I don't have capybara running, I just use rspec `type: :request` specs. How can I find out the current host (should be localhost) and port?

Comment: I would just set a constant in your `spec_helper` for host (equal to localhost).

Comment: Ok, the host is clear, but what about the port? Is there a way to find out, on which port rspec is running rails?

Comment: if you're always going to run these on localhost:3000 then no need for multiple variables/constants, just do what's best for your current project.

Comment: But the tests itself aren't running on port 3000. Its some random port

Comment: probably worth another SO question regarding your specific setup.

Comment: For our Rails 3.2/Grape app, I needed to rescue from a different error: `MultiJson::ParseError`. YMMV.